# Can VSCode show me some indication when I'm editing the file that is behind origin?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Now I can see only the number of commits my current repository is behind.
And using gitlens I can see the list of commits I'm behind for the entire repository, not for the current file.
Gitlens file history shows only the local history, without origin commits that are before me.
I want to see some warning indication that editing current file without pulling it first will more likely result to merging when I will push it to the origin.

Comment: That is simply not possible. If you edit a file that is up to date, and while you're editing someone pushes a change, what do you expect to happen? That some plugin would automatically fetch the repository (not "pull", but "fetch"), run a git diff and give you a warning? And when would the fetch occur? Also, if you modify a file, commit and push after someone has already pushed, git will tell you to pull before pushing. Maybe you'll get merge conflicts and solve them, or maybe you won't, but the point is: let git do its job.

Comment: I already have a Git:Autofetch enabled in VSCode. So why not make the diff automatically for current file?

Comment: There is no "someone-pushed-new-code" event. Autofetch works by **periodically** checking what's new. So if someone pushes during the interval of autofetch, you'll still have the same problem.

Comment: It's just a warning, to know that someone made changes to the same files that I'm working on. Periodic checking is just fine.